# How to set shortcut in pyqt5 so that the shortcut can be set from a string variable?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, keyboard-shortcuts

Below code does not activate the shortcut

```
print("hmmmmm",(s))
self.actionOpen.setShortcut(_translate("MainWindow", s))
```

the output from print is

```
hmmmmm Ctrl+Y
```

but if i give the sting directly like

```
print("hmmmmm",(s))
self.actionOpen.setShortcut(_translate("MainWindow", "Ctrl+Y"))
```

the shortcut works

Comment: Are you sure that `s` is a string? What is the output of `_translate("MainWindow", s)`? Can you share a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Okay just keep in mind that `actionOpen` is part of the Designer garbage code and what it really is -- if you look closer -- is simply `QtWidgets.QAction` then if you look up `QAction` you will see that it requires a `QString` now when you supply `"Ctrl+Y"` within the call Python/PyQt translates that into a QString for you but when you supply a variable containing that same value it does not translate it into a QString thus to do what you are trying to do (which using the Designer is the wrong way to go about it in the first place) you have to convert your string into a QString

Comment: @DennisJensen There is no `QString` in PyQt5, so you cannot convert anything into one . And in any case, the OP is using `setShortcut`, which takes a `QKeySequence`. This class defines a [QVariant operator](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qkeysequence.html#operator-QVariant), which means a string can be passed to any API which requires a `QKeySequence`. So, as already pointed out above, the only thing of interest here is exactly what `_translate("MainWindow", s)` returns when the OP runs the code.

Comment: provide a [MRE] if you want help

Comment: Thanks @ekhumoro for that correction - I just keep encountering examples of Qt4 when doing Qt5 searches and sometimes forget they removed QString except I recall having to explicitly convert something from QString to str recentish so it seems maybe it has not been removed 100% *shrug* not worth diving to deeply into just do not use them.

Comment: So is that `_translate("MainWindow", s)` the OPs own code or something the Designer created like it created the `actionOpen` variable

Comment: @DennisJensen The OPs second (working) example looks like auto-generated code from Qt Designer. If so, `_translate` would be an alias for `QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate`. However, it only really makes sense to use *string literals* with translation functions, so the OPs first example looks fishy. If `s` is something that Qt can convert into a `QKeySequence` (such as a string), the code should simply be: `self.actionOpen.setShortcut(s)`. If still required, the translation of the contents of `s` would need to be done elsewhere.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answers.Actually the variable is string, i even typecast it to string but it doesn't work. Since there is no qstring in pyqt i am still confused about what to do.It is not possible to give the string directly as i need the shortcut to vary accordingly.Again thank you for your valuable input it helped me even further to understand the problem.

Comment: Do you really need to Translate it are you dealing in multiple languages or just one single language?

Comment: Hi Guys,Finally found the issue, its because I do filepointer.read() twice and the seek was set to eof, thank you for the respones. Sorry that it was my dum mistake